# Vectorization of pandas groupby using conditional filters

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, group-by, vectorization

Let's say I have a sample `df`, such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['William', 1, 0, 'T', 0, 1],['James', 0, 1, 'R', 1, 1],['James', 1, 0, 'S', 0, 1],['Dean', 1, 0, 'R', 1, 0],['William', 0, 1, 'S', 0, 0],['James', 0, 0, 'S', 0, 1]],columns=['Name','x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'])
```

Which gives:

```
      Name  x1  x2 x3  x4  x5
0  William   1   0  T   0   1
1    James   0   1  R   1   1
2    James   1   0  S   0   1
3     Dean   1   0  R   1   0
4  William   0   1  S   0   0
5    James   0   0  S   0   1
```

Now, I want to group the dataframe by `Name`, so:

```
grouped = df.groupby('Name')
```

I want to then iterate through a list of variables and perform some calculations on each of these groups, using each of those variables as the column name and applying a specific filter on the passed group, for example:

```
def my_function(x, i):

    stats = [x[i].sum(),
            x[x['x3']=='L'][i].sum(),
            x[x['x3']=='R'][i].sum(),
            x[(x['x2']==1) | (x['x4']==1) | (x['x5']==1)][i].sum(),
            x[x['x2']==1][i].sum(),
            x[x['x2']==0][i].sum(),
            x[x['x5']==1][i].sum()]

    return pd.Series(stats)

for i in ['x1','x2','x4','x5']:
    out = grouped.apply(lambda x: my_function(x, i))
```

This might seem to perform fast for the small sample dataframe, however for a dataframe with ~5000 columns, ~50 rows, and ~20 unique names, this can take a good amount of time to finish. I know that there are likely opportunities for vectorization or optimization of this approach.

Is there a way to vectorize the process above, knowing that I will need to filter the data in the same manner for each of the variables in the outer loop?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

**EDIT (following Wen's comment):**

I placed my variables and conditional filters to perform on the original `df` into separate lists, then performed a `groupby()` on the resulting filtered dataframes, and calculated the corresponding `sum()` for each of the variables.

```
variables = ['x1','x2','x4','x5']
filters = [df['x3']=='S', df['x3']=='R', (df['x2']==1) | (df['x4']==1) | (df['x5']==1), df['x2']==1, df['x2']==0, df['x5']==1]

out = [df[i].groupby('Name')[j].sum() for i in filters for j in variables]
```

I imagine I just need to `concat` the outputs into a single output dataframe, but will this insert missing values for the cases that did not return a sum? For example, `'Dean'` will not return 0 for `df['x3']=='S'`, is there a way to do so?

Comment: How about calculated them one by one, then concat it back ?

Comment: Do you mean the filters one by one?

Comment: Yes , filter each conditions before groupby

Comment: I'll give it a try, but this would mean I need to explicitly create a new dataframe with the filter applied for each of these filters, and I have a good amount of them...

Comment: no matter what you need to write them into your function, if the speed do matter, why not create them one by one then concat back to your expected df

Comment: I'll make an edit to my OP to reflect the changes I made, performance is light-years better. Thank you for the suggestion.